# MySQL: Return parent rows conditionally on two children of that parent which are the same table

Tags: mysql, alias

I have the following setup in MySQL:

- Table `Game`: `gameid`, `p1state`, `p2state`
- Table `PlayerGamestate`: `playergamestateid`, `ready`

`p1state` and `p2state` are foreign keys into `PlayerGamestate`. I want to return all Games which have BOTH `p1state` and `p2state` marked as `ready=1`. Is this possible in a single query?

I am using php to access if that matters but I would prefer to do it in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
SELECT GameID
FROM Game G
INNER JOIN PlayerGameState GS1 on G.P1state = GS1.PlayerGamestateID
INNER JOIN PlayerGameState GS2 On G.P2State = GS2.PlayerGameStateID
WHERE GS1.ready=1 and GS2.ready=1
```